# VirtueMart Sub Categories Display

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

Im trying to modify the virtue mart categories and Im having troubles in these. I want to do something like this;

```
Clothes ( Parent )

  -Toddler ( Child )

     -- Upper ( Child )
       --- T Shirt 1
       --- T Shirt 2
       --- T Shirt 3

     -- Lower ( Child )
       --- Pants 1
       --- Pants 2
       --- Pants 3
```

When the user clicks on the "Toddler" sub category, the page will display all the products (T Shirt 1- 3 and Pants 1 - 3) by its another sub category ( Upper and Lower)

Anyone who can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't listed your VM version [duh..], You need to might want to check out [Cherry Picker VM](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-products-search/10328) or any Virtuemart Filter that is listed supported to your version.

1. [VMF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-products-search/10285)
2. [VM Filter Pro](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-products-search/13773)
3. [Cat filters](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-products-search/10968)

Some filter by different means, but it sounds like what you need to achieve isn't available out of the box.